# How can I get realtime auto-completion on Python instead of having to press <ctrl-x> <ctrl-o> in Vim?

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

Currently, I have these plugins in Vim running on `zsh` shell:

- `Valloric/YouCompleteMe`
- `davidhalter/jedi-vim`

The vim also has support for Python 2 and Python 3.

I would like Vim to do autocompletion for every keystroke in realtime instead of having to press `<ctrl-x>`,`<ctrl-o>`, which is cumbersome.  How can I achieve it? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @awiebe. But sorry, that was not my question.

Comment: "How can I achieve it?" By reading the documentation of those two plugins.

Comment: I will read it.  If everyone else reads the documentation too, then this site will have less users and will be less active. Fyi, I am just excited to learn from others since I am new in Vim and being a part of a community who assists others who are in need gives you more motivation to learn new things. Also, I can learn from the experience of others who have gone through the same problem before.  Thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: 1. The very existence of this site and others before it is a *symptom* of larger issues that plague the programming world: laziness and entitlement. 2. How do you think the top answerers on SO got the knowledge you are hoping to tap from? 3. The authors of those plugins have written an extensive documentation, do them the courtesy of reading it. It has all the information you need. 4. If you are new to Vim you have more important things to do than installing bloated plugins. 5. *You* obviously didn't even try to find a solution to *your* problem. Passivity is not how programming works.

Comment: If you do not want to share it, then I am fine with that. Pleade dont assume I am lazy just because I ask questions here. There are many ways to learn things. If I decide to install those plugins, who are you to say that those are bloated plugins? I think it will help me and if you dont, then I have never judged you. If I were passive, then I wouldnt even attempt arch linux and vim. I could just use windows and word which is the norm. You just assume too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [acp.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879) (formerly named AutoComplPop) automatically opens the completion popup as you type. With the .,w,b,k configuration, you can make it use different completion sources, like *omni* or *dictionary* completion. [neocomplete](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim) apparently also has this feature. Maybe this is already included in YouCompleteMe, too. Might be worth reading its documentation.